# Any tool or method to ease the process of writing media queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I'm looking for some tool that can allow writing media queries in real time, while doing something like - inspecting in google chrome and adjusting code as needed. One such tool is shown in this video-
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXTP8XqrSwE&t=613s
But it's not maintained anymore and seems broken now. So, fellow developers please share anything similar or better than this tool that might be of some help.

Comment: response for brackets..

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: As they are very easy to write, learn how to write them manually and it will save more time than to start up a tool

Comment: http://filehippo.com/download_brackets/ ... Try  To use brackets ..

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar The tool you mentioned doesn't work anymore, which is what was shown in video as well. Unfortunate me !!

Comment: http://opensourceforu.com/2017/02/top-12-web-design-tools-2017/

Comment: try this .............

Comment: Dev Console of any browser do all that you need about adjusting while seeing the frontend, I don't undestand why you want other tool.

Comment: @CarlosAlexandre Looking for something better than this. Consoles aren't meant to persist changes really.